# Converting a simple array to object

Tags: javascript

```js
var arr = [ 'key', 'value' ];
console.log(arr);

var obj = { arr[0] : arr[1] };
console.log(obj);
```

I'm getting an error doing this array to object conversion. However, this isn't a problem:

```js
var arr = [ 'key', 'value' ];
var key = arr[0];
var value = arr[1];

var obj = { key : value };
console.log(obj);
```

Why doesn't the array substitution work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: The second version is equally problematic. The property's key will be `key`, not the value you get from the array. Should be `var obj = { [key] : value };`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
var arr = [ 'key', 'value' ];
console.log(arr);

var obj = { [arr[0]] : arr[1] };
console.log(obj);
```

I think the problem is in the key part. have a look how i did it.

Comment: this is a very confusing syntax. Would you mind changing your answer so that the code  is a bit more  declarative?
In my opinion, something like:
var obj = {};
obj[arr[0]] = arr[1]; 

Would be easier to understand.

Comment: the person who asked this question has very good reputation. so i posted this answer keeping in mind that he must be an expert. but sure your way is also perfect. meanwhile someone has posted a link of possible duplicate where your answer is also mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You need a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for an object literal.

```
{ [key]: value }
  ^^^^^           left hand side brackets, takes value of key
```